# When trying to call a credit screen function from my title screen function the credit screen won't load

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Here is my credit screen function:

```
def game_credit():
    credit = True
    timer = 0
    while credit:
        print("In Loop")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        print(credit)
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        #gameDisplay.blit(img_screen_title, [0,0,display_width,display_height])
        button("BACK", black, "medium", button_x, 260, 180, 59, title_screen(), img_button, img_button_highlight)
        pygame.display.update()


        clock.tick(FPS)
```

This is my title screen function:

```
def title_screen():
    title = True
    #pygame.mouse.set_cursor(img_cursor, hotspot, xormasks, andmasks)

    while title:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    title = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    game_credit()

        gameDisplay.blit(img_screen_title, [0,0,display_width,display_height])
        button("START", black, "medium", button_x, 260, 180, 59, img_button, img_button_highlight, action="start")
        button("CREDITS", black, "medium", button_x, 322, 180, 59, img_button, img_button_highlight, action="credit")
        button("QUIT", black, "medium", button_x, 384, 180, 59, img_button, img_button_highlight, action="quit")
        message_to_screen("A FANGAME by Scott Kiistner", white, 280, "small2")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

And here is the Button Function referenced earlier:

```
def button(text, text_color, text_size, x, y, width, height, inactive_img=img_button, active_img=img_button_highlight, action=None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active_img, [x,y])
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "credit":
                game_credit()
            elif action == "start":
                gameLoop()
            elif action == "quit":
                gameQuit()



    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive_img, [x,y])


    text_to_button(text, text_color, x, y, width, height, text_size)
```

When I run the script, no errors are shown and it runs, but when I try to click into the credits menu, it just stays on the title screen, however when I go to click into the start menu or quit menu, they both work as well.

I am relatively new to Python, so I might just be missing something obvious, but I've tried searching up my problem and finding a solution, however I cannot.

Here is also my game loop function, or the one I get too by clicking on the start button:

```
def gameLoop():

    gameExit = False
    FPS = 30

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameQuit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    gameQuit()
        gameDisplay.fill(blue)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: add many `print()` with usefull text/comment/variables to see what is going on in program. maybe it helps you to find incorrect variable, or incorrect  `if/else` expression.

Comment: btw: `PyGame` has class `pygame.Rect()` to keep `x,y,width,height` and it can be use to check collision between button rectangle and mouse position.

Answer (score 1):

It is only guess. I can't run your code to check it.

Your code looks OK. But maybe there is problem because you use `mouse.get_pressed()` and computers are too fast for human.

`mouse.get_pressed()` informs than you are keeping button pressed.

You keep button pressed - for example 100ms - but computer in the same time calls `game_credit` and it see `BACK` button in the same place as `CREDITS` button (but you still keep button pressed) and it think that you click this button so it returns to title screen. (and then it thing you pressed `CREDIT` button and it calls `game_credit`, etc.)

You should use `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` because it is true only when button changes state from UP to DOWN. It is false when you are keeping button DOWN.